# XmlAttribute / XmlElement in Interface (Element Name not changed when Serialized) - Why?

Tags: c#, xml, interface, xml-serialization, xml-attribute

When I add an "XmlAttribute/XmlElement" to a property in an Interface and 100 other classes inherit from this interface, when Serializing the object to XML - why doesn't the attributename I entered show up in the XML file after serialization?

```
interface Test
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    bool PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

when saving the file, is shows "PropertyName" and not "Name".

Is there any way to make it work, so a proeprty with an XmlAttributes added to an interface changes the Value everywhere instead of Value because if a few classes inherit from the same interface it takes alot of time to add all those Attributes to all those classes that inherit it, and it would be easier to change the Name of the Attribute instead of changing a 100 of them.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deukalin, spent some time and make it work with comprehensive tree of classes and interfaces.

Here is the working code

```
    public interface ITestX
    {
        [XmlAttribute("NameX")]
        string PropertyNameX { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITestY
    {
        [XmlAttribute("NameY")]
        string PropertyNameY { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITestZ
    {
        [XmlAttribute("NameZ")]
        string PropertyNameZ { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class TestC : ITestZ
    {
        public abstract string PropertyNameZ { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class TestA : TestC, ITestX, ITestY
    {
        public abstract string PropertyNameX { get; set; }
        public abstract string PropertyNameY { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestB : TestA
    {
        public override string PropertyNameX { get; set; }
        public override string PropertyNameY  { get; set; }
        public override string PropertyNameZ { get; set; }
    }

    public static class ClassHandler
    {
        public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, bool inherit) where T : Attribute
        {
            object[] attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), inherit);

            return attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0 ? null : attributes[0] as T;
        }

        public static void GetXmlAttributeOverrides(XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, Type type)
        {
            if (type.BaseType != null)
            {
                GetXmlAttributeOverrides(overrides, type.BaseType);
            }

            foreach (Type derived in type.GetInterfaces())
            {
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in derived.GetProperties())
                {
                    XmlAttributeAttribute xmlAttributeAttribute = ClassHandler.GetCustomAttribute<XmlAttributeAttribute>(propertyInfo, true) as XmlAttributeAttribute;

                    if (xmlAttributeAttribute == null)
                        continue;

                    XmlAttributes attr1 = new XmlAttributes();
                    attr1.XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute();
                    attr1.XmlAttribute.AttributeName = xmlAttributeAttribute.AttributeName;
                    overrides.Add(type, propertyInfo.Name, attr1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlAttributeOverrides XmlAttributeOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
            ClassHandler.GetXmlAttributeOverrides(XmlAttributeOverrides, typeof(TestB));
            try
            {
                TestB xtest = new TestB() { PropertyNameX = "RajX", PropertyNameY = "RajY", PropertyNameZ = "RajZ" };

                StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();
                using (XmlWriter xtw = XmlTextWriter.Create(xmlString))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestB), XmlAttributeOverrides);
                    serializer.Serialize(xtw, xtest);

                    xtw.Flush();
                }

                Console.WriteLine(xmlString.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
}
```

Below is the output of sample above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><TestB xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/
XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" NameZ="RajZ" Na
meX="RajX" NameY="RajY" />
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Should GetXmlAttributeOverrides no longer return a value?

Comment: I'll add a layout of my classes.

Comment: When I implement the property from the Attribute interfaces, I add "public bool override PropertyName { get { return _propertyName; } set { _propertyName = value; } }" which gives me the error "no suitable method found to override", can this be the reason for it not to take the interfaces XmlAttribute value?

Answer (score 1):

I altered the code to suit my project more. What I did was this:

```
    public static XmlAttributeOverrides GetXmlAttributeOverrides(Type type)
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

        foreach (Type derived in ClassHandler.GetImplementedInterfaces(type))
        {

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in derived.GetProperties())
            {
                XmlAttributeAttribute xmlAttributeAttribute = ClassHandler.GetCustomAttribute<XmlAttributeAttribute>(propertyInfo, true) as XmlAttributeAttribute;

                if (xmlAttributeAttribute == null) continue;

                XmlAttributes attr1 = new XmlAttributes();
                attr1.XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute();
                attr1.XmlAttribute.AttributeName = xmlAttributeAttribute.AttributeName;
                overrides.Add(type, propertyInfo.Name, attr1);
            }
        }

        return overrides;
    }
```

The object I'm trying on which implements an inteface with properties all have "[XmlAttributeAttribute(SomeName)] over them.

Still, when I serialize it gives the same results. I don't get the Attribute value from the interface.

This is how I serialize:

```
    public static void SerializeFile(String filename, object obj, bool deleteIfExists = true)
    {

        if (deleteIfExists)
        {
            FileManager.DeleteFile(filename);
        }

        Type[] extraTypes = ClassHandler.GetPropertiesTypes(obj, true);

        using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            //XmlSerializer xmlSerialize = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), extraTypes); 
            XmlSerializer xmlSerialize = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), GetXmlAttributeOverrides(obj.GetType()), extraTypes, null, null);
            xmlSerialize.Serialize(stream, obj);
        }
    }
```

the two methods I use from my ClassHandler class:

```
    public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, bool inherit) where T : Attribute
    {
        object[] attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), inherit);

        return attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0 ? null : attributes[0] as T;
    }

    public static List<Type> GetImplementedInterfaces(Type type)
    {
        Type[] types = type.GetInterfaces();
        List<Type> lTypes = new List<Type>();

        foreach(Type t in types)
        {
            lTypes.Add(t);
        }

        return lTypes;
    }
```

classes have the following structure:

```
interface IAnimal
{
    // Properties
    // Methods
}

public abstract class Animal : IAnimal
{
    // Implements IAnimal properties and methods
    // This XmlElement gets written correctly when XML Serializing
    // Example:
    [XmlElement("AnimalAge")]
    public double Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }
}

public abstract class Bird : Animal, IAttributeWings
{
    // Implements Attributes common for all "Birds"
    // Setting "override" here gives me error
    public bool HasWings { get { return _hasWings; } set { _hasWings = value; } }
}

public class Pelican : Bird, IAttributeCanFly
{
    // Implements Attributes common for all "Pelicans"
    // Does not implement previous attribute IAttributeWings since Bird class does this
    // Setting "override" here gives me error as well
    public bool CanFly { get { return _canFly; } set { _canFly = value; } }
}
```

and then the attribute interfaces only have properties like "bool CanFly, bool hasWings" and such and other attributes for a specific category like in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Some reason it does not work in .NET... But I come up with this solution to overcome the problem you have using **XmlAttributeOverrides**. For more information about it, please visit the below link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides.aspx

You can optimize it by refactoring / caching this **GetXmlAttributeOverrides()** method somewhere in your application. Hope it helps.

```
public interface ITest
{
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    string PropertyName { get; set; }
}

public class XTest : ITest
{
    public string PropertyName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            XTest xtest = new XTest() { PropertyName = "Raj" };

            StringBuilder xmlString = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter xtw = XmlTextWriter.Create(xmlString))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XTest), GetXmlAttributeOverrides(typeof(XTest)));
                serializer.Serialize(xtw, xtest);

                xtw.Flush();
            }

            Console.WriteLine( xmlString.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

   public static XmlAttributeOverrides GetXmlAttributeOverrides(Type derivedType)
   {
       Type type = typeof(ITest);
       XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

       XmlAttributes attr = new XmlAttributes();

       foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
       {
           XmlAttributeAttribute xmlAttributeAttribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(XmlAttributeAttribute), true) as XmlAttributeAttribute;

           if (xmlAttributeAttribute == null) continue;

           XmlAttributes attr1 = new XmlAttributes();
           attr1.XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute();
           attr1.XmlAttribute.AttributeName = xmlAttributeAttribute.AttributeName;
           overrides.Add(derivedType, propertyInfo.Name, attr1);
       }

       return overrides;
   }
}
```

**EDIT:** Include this extension class in your application

```
public static class PropertyInfoEx
{
        public static T GetCustomAttribute<T>(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo, bool inherit) where T : Attribute
        {
            object[] attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), inherit);

            return attributes == null || attributes.Length == 0 ? null : attributes[0] as T;
        }

}
```

Comment: If I were to use your method, don't I have to specify which interace it implements each time I create an XmlAttributeOverride? Therefor, making it exactly the same as before. All the objects implements one interface, from there different type of classes implements other interfaces too; so it's not just one that needs to be overriden and each time I want to serialize XML I have to specify exactly which interfaces. Also, my program is based on finding classes that implements the first interface and I use them in the program dynamically. If I add a new class, the program adds it automatically .

Comment: I'm just gave jump-start direction to make it work. Nothing out there out of the box. You may want to extend it to meet your needs.

Comment: Also, this occurs: System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' does not contain a definition for 'GetCustomAttribute' and no extension method 'GetCustomAttribute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please include PropertyInfoEx extension class in your app. See above EDIT.

Comment: I added a new answer (since it contained my code) above. Please check if there's something I'm missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Any ideas about my code that entered? I added the classes "layout". If you could give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Found some issues in your code. Below is the corrected code

```
public static XmlAttributeOverrides GetXmlAttributeOverrides(Type type)
{
    XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();

    // Get all interfaces that the "type" implements (is it same as "derivedType" from previously)?
    foreach (Type derived in ClassHandler.GetImplementedInterfaces(type))
    {

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in derived.GetProperties())
        {
            XmlAttributeAttribute xmlAttributeAttribute = ClassHandler.GetCustomAttribute<XmlAttributeAttribute>(propertyInfo, true) as XmlAttributeAttribute;

            if (xmlAttributeAttribute == null) continue;

            XmlAttributes attr1 = new XmlAttributes();
            attr1.XmlAttribute = new XmlAttributeAttribute();
            attr1.XmlAttribute.AttributeName = xmlAttributeAttribute.AttributeName;
            overrides.Add(type, propertyInfo.Name, attr1);
        }
    }

    return overrides;
}
```

Try for yourself. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Still the same. I'll edit my earlier post (with my version of your code) and add the class that gets the interfaces that it implements. I get results from it, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Class A = Abstract class that implements an interface, Class B = inherits class A, a category of class A (subclass), Class C = an object in the category, where the object gets created from. Class C then implements unique Attribute interfaces that it gets properties from.

Comment: Please post sample class hierarchy you describing it above.